# How to restore or copy component templates?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Where can I find file where my component templates are stored? What if I need to copy it to another machine or just restore it when reinstalling my system?
Strange, but I can't find an answer to this seemingly simple question for the second day. Thank you!

Comment: 1)  Which Delphi version?  2) What do you mean by "component templates" exactly: frames, things (forms, etc) that you've added to the repository or what?

Comment: “What do you mean by "component templates" exactly: frames, things (forms, etc)” - Frames are frames, things are things - so, by analogy - component templates are component templates - from my point of view it has one distinct meaning - you select some component on your form, then select Component -> Create Component Template - that’s it...

Comment: BTW, I'm not sure why this got a down-vote, as the q asks for just the sort of info which tends to be hard to come by from the docs.

Comment: You answered question 2. Now please answer question 1 with a tag edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my install of Delphi7, for instance, my Delphi setup is in D:\D7 and the component templates are in the file `D:\D7\Bin\Delphi.DCT`, which must be the default because I never use component templates.

In D7, Delphi.DCT is a binary file which appears to contain all the user-installed component templates, so I imagine (not tested) that copying it to the corresponding location on another machine is all you would need to do.

Fwiw I found the DCT file by saving a component template with an unusual name, then did a text search through my Delphi install directory and below to find which file contained the name.  D7 pre-dates of course the more "modern" storage locations MS dreamt up.

For later versions, mine are located in `%AppData%\Roaming\Embarcadero\BDS\{version}\bds.dct` on Win10, e.g. mine for Seattle is located in `C:\Users\MA\AppData\Roaming\Embarcadero\BDS\17.0`

Comment: %AppData%\Embarcadero\BDS\{version}\bds.dct

Comment: I’ve already search for .dct files on my computer. I didn’t find it. (I use Delphi XE5). I think in XE they don’t use it anymore…

Comment: If you look at TOndrej's comment, you'll see that the name is now BDS.DCT - my PC has several instances, for XE4, XE8, Seattle, etc

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, didn't notice your comment TOndrej at once - found it at last with your help.

Comment: Sorry again! It's dst files, not dct. So still unable to locate where these files are kept...

Comment: Well, my Seattle .DCT file **does** contain the test template I added to it just now and my h/disk doesn't have **any** .DST files.

Comment: Thank you MartynA. At last I found it too. Just by mistake deleted my test template and fogot about deleting. Thanks again. I wish that they would bery it much deeper, so it wouldn't be so easy to find...