# How can I open BDS.dct (Borland Palette Template Library) file

Tags: templates, delphi, components, edit

Can I Open/Edit "bds.dct" file (Borland Palette Template Library) to add manually or programatically new component templates?

I'm using a componenteditor to create new components and I'd like to add this components at Templates pallete without use Component/Create Component Template menu item.

Comment: I'm not sure what you ask about. `Borland Palette Template Library` sounds very ancient. Do you ask about adding components to the `Tool Palette`? If so, then look at `System.Classes.RegisterComponents`

Comment: I'm talking about Create Component Template, not RegisterCompoents. BDS.dct has "Borland Palette Template Library" at first line of file. ToolsAPI references Borland in all IDE Services.  OpenToolsAPI is almost the same since version 1 of Borland Delphi, with new  funcionalities of course. BDS.dct is a repository of Component Templates. I'm trying to open/edit it.

Comment: OK, I found the file in `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Embarcadero\BDS\21.0` directory. It is a binary file, and I have no idea of how it is encoded. I guess you just have to enter your templates using the means provided in the IDE. Also see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38672329/how-to-restore-or-copy-component-templates/38672787#38672787) and [this web page](http://www.blong.com/Articles/CodeTemplates/#TemplatesWindow), which in addition to `Component Templates`, also discusses `Live Templates`. Finally, this seems to be version dependent, inform your version.